# Check on macro returned variable return condition always false

Tags: c

I have the following code in **embedded c**:

```
tu4 = getu4(i_a)*getu2(i_b)/1000;
```

I want to check that the result does not wrap u2 so I do:

```
tu2=(u2)(tu4>MAX_U2?MAX_U2:tu4);
```

But this condition gives warning condition always **false**, even if the actual values can wrap around u2.
How to get rid of the warning?

Comment: In what header is the `getu4` function declared? What are the definitions of `tu4` and `i_a` and `i_b` nad `getu4` and `getu2` and `u2` and `tu4` and `MAX_U2`? Please post reproducible, compilble code with the issue.

Comment: Are you sure tu4 is actually wider than the type u2? Maybe you also need to cast MAX_U2 in u4?